# Xcode 8 - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textView

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have a project in Xcode 8, Swift 3 and when launching the app, it immediately closes with this error.

> 2017-01-18 23:44:56.618970 EOB-Reader[18977:5233502] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key textView.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x19175d1b8 0x19019455c 0x19175ce80 0x1921918f0 0x197971e40 0x197b15af8 0x19167c034 0x197b144cc
>   0x197974e14 0x197746980 0x1976125bc 0x1976124ec 0x19774bf00
>   0x19774bd08 0x19774bb64 0x19774e80c 0x1976207dc 0x1977505f4
>   0x19774f234 0x19762a754 0x19762a4cc 0x19768ea90 0x19761a7e0
>   0x197619ab8 0x197619904 0x197618eec 0x197616138 0x19768868c
>   0x197894cb8 0x19789a808 0x1978af104 0x1978977ec 0x19333392c
>   0x193333798 0x193333b40 0x19170ab5c 0x19170a4a4 0x1917080a4
>   0x1916362b8 0x19767d7b0 0x197678534 0x100083b44 0x1906195b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

`textView` is an outlet I created previously but have since removed that line and that class and some other stuff that I did that I can't quite remember.  In any case, even though that variable is gone, it is still causing me problems.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This typically arises when one removes an outlet from code, but not from the storyboard, itself. Go to your scene, identify which control is still hooked up to that outlet, and remove it from there, too...

Comment: Thank you.  This comment helped me.